# How to sort divs based on data attribute with the change of a drop down

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have a results page that renders results in divs. these divs have several data attributes which I want to use to re-order them ascending and descending.

for example:

```
<div data-price="15000" data-pet="1" data-balcony="0">content</div>
```

I want to reorder them with a dropdown selection

```
<select>
<option value="0">Sort by</option>
<option value="1">Low price to high</option>
<option value="2">high price to low</option>
</select>
```

can someone help? the number of divs are variable.

Comment: Use Ajax maybe : when you select an option in your dropdown, sort the attr your want in php then rebuild all your div with the new order?

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to achieve this with jquery

Comment: You can use Ajax with jquery :) It allow you to reload the content of your page without reloading the page. This way you can rebuild your div sort as you want without realoding all the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is a lot, then doing it on the browser could be quite slow, it's better to do it on the server.

Here is a dirty solution using jQuery.

```js
var rooms = $('.room');
var roomList = $('#room-list');

$('#price-sort').change( function() {
    if($(this).val() == 1){
       sortAsc();
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 2){
        sortDesc();
    }
});

function sortAsc(){
    roomList.empty();
    rooms.sort(function(a, b){
      return $(a).data('price')-$(b).data('price')
    });
    roomList.append(rooms);
}
function sortDesc(){
    roomList.empty();
    rooms.sort(function(a, b){
      return $(b).data('price')-$(a).data('price')
    });
    roomList.append(rooms); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="price-sort">
<option value="0">Short by</option>
<option value="1">Low price to high</option>
<option value="2">high price to low</option>
</select>

<div id="room-list">
<div data-price="15000" data-pet="1" data-balcony="0" class="room">First - Price: 15000</div>
<div data-price="95000" data-pet="1" data-balcony="0" class="room">Second - Price: 95000</div>
<div data-price="65000" data-pet="1" data-balcony="0" class="room">Third - Price: 65000</div>
<div data-price="9000" data-pet="1" data-balcony="0" class="room">Fourth - Price: 9000</div>
<div data-price="10000" data-pet="1" data-balcony="0" class="room">Fifth - Price: 10000</div>
</div>
```

Still though, this is just an example for a small amount of elements.